# Delete a key in deictionary when iterating through the dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

#How do I delete a  key in deictionary when iterating through the dictionary?

```
for k in lst_keywords_physics_dict.keys():
    if (len(k)==1):
       lst_keywords_physics_dict.pop(k)
       break
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already doing it correctly.

for example:

```
lst_keywords_physics_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

for k in lst_keywords_physics_dict.keys():
    if len(k) == 1:
        lst_keywords_physics_dict.pop(k)
        break
```

So, what was the issue you were facing? , I can modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: I think he asked and answered to question himself, I don't know if his purpose was to gain some points.

Answer (score -1):

#We can use this method in python 3 to delete the keys when iterating throug the dictionary without getting the error regarding changing size of dictionary.

```
for k in list(lst_keywords_physics_dict.keys()):
   if (len(k)<3):
       lst_keywords_physics_dict.pop(k)
```

Comment: There is a typo in the title. deictionary -> dictionary

Comment: You are asking and you are answering, if you have found the answer then add it as a comment.